# Why did Tobi use Kurama in his attack?

Tags: naruto

After perfectly timing the Release from Kushina Uzumaki's body, Tobi attacks the village using Kurama, the Nine Tails, in chapter 501.

Why did Tobi suddenly decide to use Kurama to attack the village? He was going to need Kurama for his 'Moon plan' as well. So why did he not just take it and leave?

Comment: A decent question. I think it's because Minato showed up right then and engaged Tobi in a fight.  And who could resist trying to one-up their teacher?  Unfortunately for him it backfired.  I'm not sure if much reason was ever really stated.  This might just be a plot hole that arose from the events preceding Kurama's attack not having been planned out at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapters 501-502 never give or imply any particular reason for why exactly Tobi/Obito would attack the village at that time. Certainly, the smartest strategic choice would have been to simply extract Kurama from Kushina and immediately run for it as far and fast as they could.

The most straightforward reason is simply: rage. The Uchiha are famous for their fury, once their blood starts boiling, and it may be he simply saw red so went on a rampage with the most devastating weapon he had on hand. Remember that he had just been to Rin's grave and seen Kakashi there, reviving all those old, tormented memories, and from there had to immediately battle Minato. Minato was probably the most powerful and wily opponent he'd ever faced until that point, so battling him must have been frustrating. The combination of these events in such quick succession: boom!

Answer (score 0):

Madara was the only person who in the past could control kurama and use him as a weapon. Since Tobi wanted people to think that he was Madara he attacked the village by using kurama.

Comment: Not sure that makes sense since nobody knew it was him who did it for a long time.